# get custom output for use in convase js from php server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have a table in worodpress site and output from this table is like :

```
{
  { [line1]=> array(3) {{'x'=>'5' , 'y'=>'8},{'x'=>'5' , 'y'=>'8},{'x'=>'5' , 'y'=>'8}},
  { [line2]=> array(3) {{'x'=>'5' , 'y'=>'8},{'x'=>'5' , 'y'=>'8},{'x'=>'5' , 'y'=>'8}}
}
```

i want show chart by this data and needed output is like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
      {
        axisX: {
          title: "Thick Axis line",
          lineThickness: 6

        },
        data: [{
          type: "line",
          title: 'line1',
          dataPoints: [{ x: 5, y:8 }, { x: 5, y: 8 }]
        }, {
          type: "column",
          title: 'line2',
          dataPoints: [{ x: 5, y: 8 }, { x: 5, y: 8}]
        }
        ]
      });

    chart.render();
  }
</script>
```

how convert php output to custom needed data?

Of course, the number of lines is different and can be from one line to 20 lines

Comment: Not going to be easy as that is not valid JSON

Comment: Is the output provided a print_r() result of an array or do you get that string?

Comment: It is print_r()

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Where did you get stuck? We'll help you if necessary with the conversion, but unless it's pretty trivial, don't expect people to do all the work for you. See also [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code help you:

```
<?php 
    //your output
    var_dump($php_output) ;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var point = <?php echo json_encode($php_output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

    function convase_needed_output() {
       var output= [];

       for (let i in point) {
        var custom_output = '';
        custom_output = {type: "spline", dataPoints: point[i]};

        output.push(custom_output);
       }

      return output;
    }

//convase js exmaple
window.onload = function() {
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

    title: {
      text: "php to convase needed output"
    },
    data: convase_needed_output()
  });

  chart.render();
}
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).